# External control and hovering of jQuery UI Carousel 1.0.2

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal, carousel

Recently I'm working with [jQuery UI Carousel](http://drupal.org/project/uicarousel) (1.0.2) on my Drupal website. So far so good, everything is working without a problem but I'm looking for a way to add some external controls. You know, those little dots beneath the images where the user can navigate from and pinpoint a certain slide.

I took a look to the JS file (you can see it [here](http://www.lpamina.com/sites/all/modules/uicarousel/js/lib/jquery.ui.carousel.js)), but didn't find any proof of such a controls.
Right now, I was only able to write some crappy code who didn't work at all... (so I'm not gonna post it to save you some laughs :))

Anyone with some experience regarding this subject?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have specific experience with the jQuery UI Carousel module, but if you are using Views to generate the content in the carousel, you could always use [Views Slideshow](http://drupal.org/project/views_slideshow). It allows you to add a pager (either numbers or thumbnail images) to your slideshow (carousel).

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not allowed to change the chosen module. I need to use the Carousel...